# Scala pass array as parameter to Postgres jdbc sql statement

Tags: scala, playframework, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to pass an array to the prepared statement of a SQL query, using the below code

```
val arr = Array("id1", "id2", "id3")
val sqlArr = connection.createArrayOf("varchar", arr.toArray)
stmt.setArray(1, sqlArr)
stmt.executeQuery()
```

i'm getting this error,

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = character varying[]
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

sql query, that i'm using

```
select col1, col2 from someTable where col3 in (?) and col4 != 'no';
```

i also tried changing the parameter type to `VARCHAR`, `text`.

When I print the prepared statement it looks like this.

```
select col1, col2 from someTable where col3 in ('{"id1", "id2", "id3"}') and col4 != 'no';
```

I'm having trouble, on how to proceed, any help would be appreciated

I'm using scala 2.12

Comment: would suggest to have a look at [anorm](https://playframework.github.io/anorm/) rather than raw JDBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing the `in` to `any =` in the sql query worked out for me.